# how to scrape image src from homeshopping.pk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i tried following code but he is showing progressive gif image src instead of original image shown in browser

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan?page=1&AjaxRequest=1"
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")
div = soup.find_all('div', class_='innerp')
for division in div:
    image = division.find('img', class_="img-responsive")["src"]
    print(image)
```

But this code shows following results
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `['src']` attribute print `data-src` to get the path of the image:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan?page=1&AjaxRequest=1"
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")

div = soup.find_all('div', class_='innerp')
for division in div:
    image = division.select_one('img.img-responsive')['data-src']
    print(image)
```

Prints:

```
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/e/629/iphone-xs-max-pakistan__77506_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/u/724/Apple_iPhone_XS_Max_%284G__256GB_Gold%29__86582_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/q/375/1__58638_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/m/071/iphone11-black-select-2019__99988_thumb.png
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/c/923/note10_256gb-black_-minn__51011_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/k/303/iphone-11-pro-max-space-pakistan__86401_thumb.png
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/o/722/samsung-galaxy-a71-a715-128gb-dual-sim-blue__62457_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/y/370/71G1FCIP1EL._SL1500___25143_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/g/906/vivo-s1-128gb-skyline-blue-4gb-ram-__95991_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/w/375/samsung-galaxy-a31-a315-4gb-128gb-dual-sim-blue__12319_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/s/729/Samsung-Galaxy-A51-600x600__14872_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/n/179/itel-A25-1-2__18679_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/a/940/Infinix-Hot-8-a__91944_thumb.png
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/g/488/Realme-6-Comet-Blue-1__03862_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/k/364/Vivo-Y11__28500_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/j/460/samsung-galaxy-fold-5g-2__57605_zoom__77077_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/c/950/Apple_iPhone_7_Plus_%2832GB__Gold%29_Without_Facetime_1_Year_Official_Warranty__33040_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/x/022/61vlByKsTSL._AC_SX679___91001_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/e/023/images__40621_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/i/979/s10-plus-black-hd-1__91254_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/n/574/135743-v1-tecno-spark-go-mobile-phone-large-1__54522_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/k/518/61vlByKsTSL._AC_SX679___72377_thumb.jpg
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/a/035/37e49fd768e1cdce2b2b0bc7a3f8baa4__11345_thumb.png
https://cdn.homeshopping.pk/product_images/b/952/InfinixSmart4-b__55934_thumb.jpg
```